# Access Spring's RequestEntity within Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

In my Spring Boot (2.1.4) app, I need to access the `RequestEntity` in my Interceptor's `preHandle` method. Unfortunately, I seem to be unable to get an instance of it.

My code is basically this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity getSomething()
    // public ResponseEntity getSomething(RequestEntity<String> requestEntity) // doesn't work either
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("test", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and an Interceptor like this:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
{
    // doesn't work:
    // @Autowired RequestEntity<String> requestEntity;

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception) throws Exception {}

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {}

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest requestServlet, HttpServletResponse responseServlet, Object handler) throws Exception
    {

        // ACCESS TO org.springframework.http.RequestEntity NEEDED HERE!

        // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION!
        requestEntity.getHeaders();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Whether I inject RequestEntity into the Controller or not, I seem to have no way to access the (incoming) request's `RequestEntity`. I tried to `@Autowire` it into the Interceptor, but to no avail.

Any way to access this?

Comment: Springs RequestEntity should be Typed. what type is it? do you have a data object you are trying to use. include that. it doesn't look like you are doing anything that would require more than just the httpRequest

Comment: Assume ```RequestEntity<String>```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Request Entity doing something like this in your preHandle method

```java
 HttpEntity requestEntity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request).getEntity();
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: It seems this is referring to the `org.apache.http.HttpEntity` interface, whereas the OP probably means the (subclass) of `org.springframework.http.HttpEntity` class, which is a completely different?

Answer (score 0):

If you want intercept the headers in `preHandle`, instead of `requestEntity.getHeaders()`, you can use:

```
requestServlet.getHeaderNames();
```

This method has:

```
/**
 * Returns an enumeration of all the header names this request contains. If
 * the request has no headers, this method returns an empty enumeration.
 * <p>
 * Some servlet containers do not allow servlets to access headers using
 * this method, in which case this method returns <code>null</code>
 *
 * @return an enumeration of all the header names sent with this request; if
 *         the request has no headers, an empty enumeration; if the servlet
 *         container does not allow servlets to use this method,
 *         <code>null</code>
 */
public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames();
```

And you'll have all the headers names of the petition.
With each header name you can access the value of each header:

```
requestServlet.getHeader(headerName);
```

This method can access:

```
/**
 * Returns the value of the specified request header as a
 * <code>String</code>. If the request did not include a header of the
 * specified name, this method returns <code>null</code>. If there are
 * multiple headers with the same name, this method returns the first head
 * in the request. The header name is case insensitive. You can use this
 * method with any request header.
 *
 * @param name
 *            a <code>String</code> specifying the header name
 * @return a <code>String</code> containing the value of the requested
 *         header, or <code>null</code> if the request does not have a
 *         header of that name
 */
public String getHeader(String name);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I need the actual ``org.springframework.http.RequestEntity``` instance, not just access to the headers.